# How can I use the modules' own asset folder instead of the one in the src?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-translate, ngx-translate

this is how my projects directory looks like:

```
  app
    my-component
      components
      assets/i18n/en.json
      my-component.module.ts
    app.module
    app.component.ts and .html and
  assets
```

in my my-component.module I have the following config for the TranslateModule:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

...

imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: createTranslateLoader, deps: [HttpClient] },
      isolate: true,
    }),
  ],
```

and it's looking for the asset folder in the src, and not in my-component folder. How do I set it so it uses the one in the my-component folder?

I want to use it like this, because my-component will later be made into a custom webcomponent